# Пауза setTimeout

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив:

```
Array<{type: String, text: String, time: Number}>
```

Есть код который добавляет элементы в массив и через `n` время удаляет первый добавленный элемент:

```
add(state, info) {
  state.list.push({
    type: info.type,
    text: info.text,
  });
  setTimeout(() => state.list.shift(), info.time);
}
```

При вызове функции `add()`, если `state.list.length === 5` -  необходимо остановить выполнение этой же функции, пока `setTimeout` не будет закончен.

Как это реализовать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add(state, info) {
  let addNow = state.list.length < 5;
  if (addNow) {
    state.list.push({
      type: info.type,
      text: info.text,
    });
  } 
  setTimeout(() => {
    state.list.shift();
    if (!addNow) {
      state.list.push({
        type: info.type,
        text: info.text,
      });
    }
  }, info.time);
}
```

Comment: мне в любом случае нужно удалять элемент по истечению времени, не важно, больше или меньше 5
суть в том что это уведомления, я хочу сделать лимит на 5 штук для показа

Comment: @ryzen Ну и что?